# Ajax - How to alert part of json string?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="testing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="btnText" id="btntext" />
<input type="button" value="btnJSON" id="btnjson" />
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<? 
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '{"id": 1, "name": "abc", "email": "me123@aol.com"}';
?>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $("#btntext").click(function () {
        $.get("testing.text", function (data) {
           alert(data); 
        });
    });

    $("#btnjson").click(function () {
        $.get("testing.php", function (data) {
           alert(data);
       });
    }); 
});
```

When clicking on the button for text, the alert works just fine.
When clicking on the json button, the alert shows
'header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '{"id": 1, "name": "abc", "email": "me123@aol.com"}'

My question is, if I click the json button, how can I alert just the email to show 'me123@aol.com'?

Comment: The fact that the alert shows the entire php script text is not a good sign .. that indicates that something's wrong with the server and PHP is not being interpreted.

Comment: I, personally, prefer `console.log()` to debugging stuff than `alert()` .. but that's neither here nor there for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are runing this without a server to run the PHP, what is causing the code to appear and not  interpret. Eg. executing the html file directly and not by an http url.

After solving this, you can call `alert(data.email);` to show the e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

`data.email` will give you the value of email property.

Comment: @Melissa Kelley have u saved the page as .php and run it on the server?

Comment: @MelissaKelley you might have to parse the JSON first since the server returns it as a string.  Try JSON.parse(data).email